# Count number of files in a folder with Perl

Tags: perl

I would like to count the number of files inside a folder with Perl. With the following code I can list them, but how can I count them in Perl?

```
$dir = "/home/Enric/gfs-0.5.2016061400";
opendir(DIR, "$dir");
@FILES = grep { /gfs./ } readdir(DIR);
foreach $file (@FILES) {
    print $file, "\n";
}
closedir(DIR);
```

Comment: As always with perl add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top. `$#FILES` is one way to have the count of files but as arrays start at 0 you need to add 1 to it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find size of an array in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406807/find-size-of-an-array-in-perl)

Comment: Did you write this code yourself, or did you copy it from somewhere else? The reason I ask is because there are many things wrong with it, and if you copied it from a tutorials site or something, I would recommend avoiding that site in the future.

Comment: @FILES = grep { /gfs./ } readdir(DIR);
print join "\n", scalar(@FILES);

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn: Using `$#array` for anything other than getting the last index in `@array` is complicating things unnecessarily. Why not just use `@array` in scalar context?

Comment: @ssr1012: Your use of `join()` seems unnecessary. Why not just `print scalar(@FILES), "\n";`?

Comment: @Dave Cross: yes. your correct.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to just count them, once you have a directory open for reading you can manipulate [context](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context) so that [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) returns the list of all entries but then assign that to a scalar.  This gives you the length of the list, ie. the number of elements

```
opendir my $dh, $dir;
my $num_entries = () = readdir($dh);
```

The construct `= () =` imposes list context on `readdir` and assigns (that expression<sup>†</sup>) to a scalar, which thus gets the number of elements in that list.<sup>‡ §</sup>   See [it in perlsecret](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Goatse).  Also see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21037846/4653379).

There are clearer ways, of course, as below.

If you want to count certain kinds of files, pass the file list through [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) first, like you do. Since `grep` imposes the list context on its input `readdir` returns the list of all files, and after filtering `grep` itself returns a list.  When you assign that to a scalar you get the length of that list (number of elements), ie. your count.  For example, for all regular files and `/gfs./` files

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $dir = '/home/Enric/gfs-0.5.2016061400';
opendir my $dh, $dir  or die "Can't open $dir: $!";

my $num_files =  grep { -f "$dir/$_" } readdir($dh);
rewinddir($dh);  # so that it can read the dir again
my $num_gfs   =  grep { /gfs./ } readdir($dh);
```

(This is only an example, with `rewinddir` so that it works as it stands. To really get two kinds of files from a directory better iterate over the entries one at a time and sort them out in the process, or read all files into an array and then process that)

*Note that `readdir` returns the bare filename, without any path.* So for most of what is normally done with files we need to prepend it with the path (unless you first `chdir` to that directory). This is what is done in the `grep` block above so that the `-f` [file test (-X)](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)  has the correct filename.

If you need to use the file list itself, get that into an array and then assign it to a scalar

```
# Get the file list, then its length
my @files_gfs = map { "$dir/$_" } grep { /gfs./ } readdir($dh);
my $num_gfs = @files_gfs;
```

Here [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) builds the full path for each file. If you don't need the path drop `map { }`. Note that there is normally no need for the formal use of [scalar](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/scalar.html) on the array to get the count, like

```
my $num_gfs = scalar @files_gfs;    # no need for "scalar" here!
```

Instead, simply assign an array to a scalar instead, it's an idiom (to say the least).

If you are processing files as you read, count as you go

```
my $cnt_gfs = 0;
while (my $filename = readdir($dh)) {
    $cnt_gfs++ if $filename =~ /gfs./;
    # Process $dir/$filename as needed
}
```

Here `readdir` is in the scalar context (since its output is assigned to a scalar), and it iterates through the directory entries, returning one at a time.

A few notes

- In all code above I use the example from the question, `/gfs./` -- but if that is in fact meant to signify a literal period then it should be replaced by `/gfs\./`
- All this talk about how `readdir` returns bare filename (no path) would not be needed with [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob) (or then better [File::Glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Glob)), which does return the full path

  ```
  use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';  # (better with this)

  my @files = glob "$dir/*";
  ```

  This returns the list of files with the path `$dir/filename`.

  Not that there is *anything* wrong with `opendir`+`readdir`. Just don't forget the path.

  Yet another option is to use libraries, like [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) with its [children](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#children) method.

---

<sup>†</sup> The assignment `() = readdir $dh` itself returns a value as well, and in this case *that* whole expression (the assignment) is placed in the scalar context.

<sup>‡</sup>  The problem is that many facilities in Perl depend in their operation and return on context so one cannot always merely assign what would be a list to a scalar and expect to get the length of the list.  The `readdir` is a good example, returning a list of all entries in list context but a single entry in scalar context.

<sup>§</sup> Here is another trick for it

```
my $num_entries = @{ [ readdir $dh ] };
```

Here it is the constructor for an anonymous array (reference), `[]`, which imposes the list context on `readdir`, while the dereferencing  `@{ }` doesn't care about context and simply returns the list of elements of that arrayref. So we can assign that to a scalar and such [scalar assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54564428/4653379) returns the number of elements in that list.

Answer (score 6):

You have the list of files in `@FILES`. So your question becomes "how do I get the length of an array?" And that's simple, you simply evaluate the array in scalar context.

```
my $number_of_files = @FILES;
print $number_of_files;
```

Or you can eliminate the unnecessary scalar variable by using the `scalar()` function.

```
print scalar @FILES;
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments @Dave Cross

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for starters (this is on Windows and will include `.` , `..` and folders.  Those can be filtered out if you want only files):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $dirname = "C:/Perl_Code";
my $filecnt = 0;

opendir (DIR, $dirname) || die "Error while opening dir $dirname: $!\n";
while(my $filename = readdir(DIR)){
     print("$filename\n");
     $filecnt++;
}
closedir(DIR);
print "Files in $dirname : $filecnt\n";
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't in Perl, but if you ever need a quick way, just type this into bash command line:

```
 ls -1 | wc -l
```

`ls -1` gives you a list of the files in the directory, and `wc -l` gives you the line count. Combined, they'll give you the number of files in your directory.

Alternatively, you can call bash from Perl (although you probably shouldn't), using

```
system("ls -1 | wc -l");
```

Answer (score 0):

As a variation on [zdim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37823538), let's say you *don't* have a directory handle opened already.  In that case

```
my $num_files =()= glob("$dir/*");
```

might be more useful.  This works on the same principle as zdim's suggestion, but without the need for the `opendir` call first.

This returns the number of files *without* including `.` and `..`, at least on Linux.